# ExtJs 6.2.0: Setting Focus on a Text Field After Page Refresh

Tags: extjs, focus

I am trying to set the focus on a field in a container after the page is reloaded/refreshed in the browser, but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried using multiple listeners on the container and on the control itself with 0 luck.

```
Ext.define('Admin.viewviewer.SearchViewTab', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.searchviewtab',
    id: 'searchviewtab',
    title: 'Search',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center'
    },
    defaultFocus: 'searchInputField',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            margin: '100px 0 0 0',
            width: 800,
            
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'center'
            },
            defaults: {
                width: '100%',
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id: 'searchInputField',
                    reference: 'searchInputField',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    msgTarget: 'under',
                    name: 'uuid',
                    bind: '{searchInput}'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Execute Query',
                    formBind: true,
                    bind: {
                        text: 'Search {searchInputType}'
                    },
                    handler: 'onSearchClick',
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(cmp) {
            cmp.focus(false, 200)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean reloaded in the browser by the user? Or after loading some data by your code?

Comment: Reloaded in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `afterrender` listener of the `textfield`. Your current listener tries to focus the container, not the textfield:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    id: 'searchInputField',
    reference: 'searchInputField',
    allowBlank: false,
    msgTarget: 'under',
    name: 'uuid',
    bind: '{searchInput}',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(textfield) {
            textfield.focus();
        }
    }
},
```

Note: `defaultFocus` could also work, but it needs an [Ext.ComponentQuery](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html), also it is better to define it on the form and not the outer container.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working.

Comment: Have you removed the `defaultFocus` and the other `afterrender` listener? I tried this with classic ExtJS 7 and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes I did. This container is an item/xtype inside a Ext.tab.panel.  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It should not be a problem, because you use the listener of the textfield. I prepared a fiddle, check [this out](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3p3b). After browser reload the textfield remains. focused